# Git: how to overcome file structure restrictions?

Tags: git, svn, deployment

Real life example:

On my local wamp server my website is structured like so:

```
Example/trunk/
  lib/
  config/
  model/
  web/
    index.php/
    (other web/ content e.g. JS/, CSS/)
  app/
```

When I up try to deploy onto a VPS hosting environment, however, the file structure I must organize in is something like this:

```
public_html/
  example/
    lib/
    config/
    model/
    app/
  example.com/
    index.php/
    (other web/ content e.g. JS/, CSS/)
  example2.com/ (another domain)
  example3.com/ (another domain)
```

My only idea for a solution is for maintaining to separate repos for the original web/ and the other files contained in trunk. However, while making it possible to maintain, forces me to fundamentally divide a single project into two separate pieces...

Any ideas for a better solution??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to symlink stuff around, i.e. put the repo outside of public_html altogether and create symlinks from public_html to appropriate parts of the repo.

Answer (score 1):

The other option is to keep a clear separation between:

- source control management: your repo, with your original structure
- release management: a script able to copy the relevant parts of your repo onto your target server, with the right structure.

If you don't make any changes directly on your deployment, that is a valid option.